# How to construct Fundamental Domains

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I understand what a Fundamental Domain is, however, I have a difficulty in understanding the algorithm to construct Fundamental Domain of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Here are the lecture notes which are quite helpful:

[Keith Conrad Summer School](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/CTNTmodularforms.pdf)

In these notes, he says that $``$For some $n$, $T^ng_0 \tau$ has real part between $-1/2$ and $1/2$.$"$,(page 7, before (3.4)). Why/how $1/2$?

Our instructor says that there is an algorithm for constructing
Fundamental Domain of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. He takes a point $iy$ in upper half plane which is not stabilized by $S$ and $T$ that generate $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.(Say $2i$). ($S$ and $T$ are same in the lecture notes of Prof. Conrad). Then he looks at
the image under $S$ of $2i$, then takes a perpendicular bisector(under
hyperbolic distance) between $2i$ and $S(2i)$, takes the area of the part
where $2i$ is. Then he does the same for $T$, then he does the same for $T^{-1}$,
takes the intersecting area between them, this is the Fundamental Domain of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

What is the reasoning behind the algorithm? Where do I stop?

How do I know that I should use $T^{-1}$, too?

How do I generalize this
algorithm to construct Fundamental Domain of $\\$ $\Gamma(2)=\langle z+2, z/(2z+1)\rangle$? Is there any "practical" way to show
that this area has one orbit element from each orbit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know to use $T^{-1}$ because $T^{-1}$ is a thing. (You didn't ask about not using $S^{-1}$, did you?)

Comment: $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $S$ and $T$, so why do we use $T^{-1}$? I can guess that it is so that the length of the interval becomes $1$, but I still can not comprehend how to know to use $T^{-1}$.

Comment: OK, let's put it this way. What does it really mean "generated by S and T"? Is it simply I, S, T, and ST? Obviously no. What else?

Comment: Is not it infinite?

Comment: Exactly! So you have to do the same for all images. As you do so, you will notice that most bisectors are far away from our area and don't touch it at all. When you are done with the infinity, there will be only three of them that matter.

Comment: Why not $2$? I mean, of course intuitively I know that it can not be $2$, but I can not convince myself. Moreover, what does $T^{-1}$ is a "thing" mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102872/discussion-between-serpenche-and-ivan-neretin).

Answer (score 2):

Your post has maybe too many questions in it; it's probably better to look at them in one post at a time. So I'm going to stick to your first question.

To start with, if $g_0\tau = x+iy$ then $Tg_0\tau=(x+1)+iy$. It follows that 
$$\{T^ng_0\tau \mid n \in \mathbb Z\} = \{(x+n)+iy \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
and therefore the set of real parts of the numbers $\{T^ng_0\tau \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is equal to
$$\{x+n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
Since adding an integer does not change the fractional part of the number, there exists an integer $m$ such that $x+m \in [0,1)$. If $x+m \in [0,1/2)$ then set $n=m$, whereas if $x+m \in [1/2,1)$ then set $n=m-1$, and now you've found the integer $n$ such that $x+n \in [-1/2,1/2)$. Therefore, the real part of $T^n g_0 \tau$ is in $[-1/2,1/2]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am in my last minute panic for the exam :) And this $1/2$ originates in the mentioned algorithm I think. Moreover, I have found partial answers to my questions via http://www.f.waseda.jp/ykomori/umemoto-master.pdf  and $first$ edition of Anderson's Hyperbolic Geometry has a subject on Fundamental Polygons & Dirichlet Polygons which is quite useful. However, still I wonder why how I am supposed to know to use $T^{-1}$.

Comment: You are supposed to use all powers of $T$. That includes: $T^1=T$, $T^{-1}$, $T^2$, $T^{-2}$, and so on. The integer $n$ that you are looking for, such that the real part of $T^n g_0 \tau \in [-1/2,1/2]$, might be any integer at all, including $-1$ for example.